# How to confirm payment intent via Stripe SDK?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stripe-payments, payment

I'm developing the Android app for now and I need to implement payment using the Stripe. I'm trying to confirm a payment intent but nothing happens. Any ideas, what should I do?

I wrote this one for now on the client-side (Android app)

```
private fun initPayment() {
    // 1. Init payment configuration
    PaymentConfiguration.init(getString(R.string.stripe_publishable_testKey))
    Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 1. init payment configuration...")
    // 2. Init Stripe
    val publishableKey = PaymentConfiguration.getInstance().publishableKey
    stripe = Stripe(requireContext(), publishableKey)
    Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 2. init stripe by key: $publishableKey  ...")
    // 3. Init payment method or card
    val testCard =
        Card.create("4242424242424242", 12, 20, "123")
    Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 3. init card...")

    // 4. Creating payment intent
    Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 4. creating payment intent...")
    paymentIntentCreator.createPaymentIntent(
        amount = "100", currency = "usd", setupFutureUsage = "off_session",
        callback = object : ApiResultCallback<String> {
            override fun onSuccess(clientSecret: String) {
                // setup customer session to retrieve a payment method
                Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 4. success, key: $clientSecret")
                Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 5. collecting payment information...")

                val paramsCard =
                    testCard.toPaymentMethodParamsCard()

                val billingDetails = PaymentMethod.BillingDetails.Builder()
                    .setAddress(exampleShippingInfo.address)
                    .setName(exampleShippingInfo.name)
                    .setEmail("zaytssss@mail.ru")
                    .setPhone(exampleShippingInfo.phone)
                    .build()

                val paymentMethodCreateParams =
                    PaymentMethodCreateParams.create(paramsCard, billingDetails)

                val intentParams =
                    ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(
                        paymentMethodCreateParams,
                        clientSecret,
                        "livreur_chic://path"
                    )


                Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 6. payment confirming...")
                stripe.confirmPayment(this@PaymentFragment.requireActivity(), intentParams)

            }

            override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 4. error: ${e.localizedMessage}")
            }
        })
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    stripe.onPaymentResult(requestCode, data,
        object : ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: PaymentIntentResult) {
                // If confirmation and authentication succeeded,
                // the PaymentIntent will have user actions resolved;
                // otherwise, handle the failure as appropriate
                // (e.g. the customer may need to choose a new payment
                // method)
                when (result.intent.status) {
                    Processing ->
                        Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 6. payment confirmation status: Processing...")
                    RequiresAction ->
                        Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 6. payment confirmation status: RequiresAction...")
                    RequiresConfirmation ->
                        Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 6. payment confirmation status: RequiresConfirmation...")
                    RequiresPaymentMethod ->
                        Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 6. payment confirmation status: RequiresPaymentMethod...")
                    Succeeded ->
                        Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 6. payment confirmation status: Succeeded...")
                    RequiresCapture ->
                        Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 6. payment confirmation status: RequiresCapture...")
                    else ->
                        Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 6. Unknown status")
                }
            }

            override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                // handle error
                Timber.d("PaymentFragment: 6. payment was not confirmed, error: ${e.localizedMessage}")

            }
        })
}
```

Log: 
1. init payment configuration...
2. init stripe by key: pk_test_##### ...
3. init card...
4. creating payment intent...
4. success, key: pi_#####*secret*#######
5. collecting payment information...
6. payment confirming...

Comment: I could provide more information if need it

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd recommend following https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/android#confirm-payment-intent

Comment: @taintedzodiac I have written my code via this tutorial and the docs says that I should confirm the payment via stripe.confirmPayment(), isn't it?

Comment: The docs specify `this` where you have `this@PaymentFragment.requireActivity()`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @taintedzodiac I'm using requireActivity() because I have a single activity structure and call this method within a Fragment. But I noticed that the function is working but the result doesn't return in onActivityResult within the fragment. What should I do for it?

Comment: Seems likely that it's not returning to the proper place. I'd suggest checking/debugging exactly what it being called when the function ends and the call should be occurring.

Comment: @taintedzodiac I found the issue, onAcitvityResult doesn't occur in a fragment. I created a class that transfers the result from activity to fragment.

Comment: have you found any solution.i need to integrate the same can you please share your code.